# How to query multiple items in Neo4J, return just one in order of precedence?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am building a multi-lingual app using Neo4J with the following structure:

```
(Article)-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(Translation {lang: 'EN', default: true, text: 'Hello World'})
```

I would like users to be able to pass in a list of language preferences such as `['EN', 'ES']`. The query should return the translation for the first language on the list found. If no preferred languages are found the query should return the default language. Just one translation should be returned.

It is easy to return a list of all applicable translations. But this will waste a lot of bandwidth over millions of queries. I also tried putting in a `LIMIT 1` but the results are not in the correct order.

```
MATCH (a:Article {id: '123'})-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(t:Translation)
WHERE t.lang IN ['ES', 'EN'] OR t.default = true
RETURN a, t
```

The challenge is to return just the correct translation based on the order of precedence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `UNWIND` you can transform a list into rows that keep the order of the list.

https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/clauses/unwind/

First, get the article with the default translation language.
Then, unwind the the list with the preferred languages.
Next, look for translation with preferred language. If there is no such translation, nothing would be returned with `MATCH`. That's why `OPTIONAL MATCH` is needed, it will be `NULL` if nothing is matched.
Finally, return the first result with either the preferred (if there is any) or the default translation.

```
MATCH (a:Article {id: '123'})-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(default:Translation {default: true})
WITH a, default
UNWIND ['ES', 'EN'] AS lang
OPTIONAL MATCH (a)-[:HAS_TRANSLATION]->(t:Translation {lang: lang})
RETURN a, CASE WHEN t IS NULL THEN default ELSE t END AS t
LIMIT 1
```

*Disclaimer: I haven't tested the query.*

Comment: I tested the query and it works perfect, thank you very much!